# Two wifi networks, one via a VPN client

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn

I want to set up my home wifi network to have two available networks, one of which is permanently routed via a VPN. This is so I can have certain devices always communicating via VPN, and the rest not so.

I know (think) that a router like the Netgear Nighthawk can be set up to run as a VPN client, connecting to a paid service like NordVPN. And presumably I'd be able to run two networks on that router (one at 2.4ghz, one at 5ghz). So would it be possible to configure one of the networks to use the VPN client to route all traffic, and the other to just go straight out to the internet?

Comment: You can not run 2 *different* networks on the 2 different wifi bands of a Nighthawk with stock firmware.  I don't know if that's possible with 3rd party firmware.

Comment: I'm guessing the most simple solution is to simple run two separate wifi routers then?

Comment: Possibly, that has issues tho when you only have one public IP.  Requires careful setup and double NAT for one network, and local content won't be directly available from the *other* local network.  Whichever approach (there are several) will have trade off's.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest buying a cheap router to **have both connections separate**.

Depending where you live, you could spend 20~30 USD/EUR and get a separate router that:

- Option 1: comes with OpenVPN support
- Option 2: can be configured to run OpenWRT + LuCI + OpenVPN (for this, I would suggest you check the router model support in the [OpenWRT list](https://openwrt.org/toh/start) of supported devices)

**Why?**

- It will be way easier to setup and more stable.
- Some smart home devices don't support 5G connections.

(Someone [asked the same question in OpenWRT forums](https://forum.openwrt.org/t/setup-wireless-client-mode-with-router-through-vpn-connection/15634) in '18 and hasn't been answered as of '20)

Answer (score -1):

Just for thought, 20 yes ago I needed more bandwidth and dialup was all that was available. I used 2 landlines that connected to 2 dial up modems in the same desktop. Then I was able to configure what was then called  "Fat Pipe Internet." This provided 1 connection from my up link for an fast ether net hub. The need I had was to provide real-time tick by tick market data and was 3 seconds ahead of cnbc satellite feed. I set 56k modem ports to max throughput and it worked. I don't know if Fat Pipe Internet is even in business or has current technologhy.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.